# Reading a text file line by line in java script, xmlhttprequest not defined?

Tags: javascript, file-io

I am new to javascript and simply trying to read a text file and print out its contents line by line.

```
 function readTextFile(file)
 {
     var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
     client.open('GET', file);
     client.send();
     client.onreadystatechange = function() {
         alert(client.responseText);
     }
 }
 readTextFile("file.txt");
```

I know alert(client.responseText) isn't reading it line by line, but I am taking it step by step. I'm not even sure if XMLHttpRequest is the way to do this but its what I have been seeing when I search around for some help.

The error message I get off the bat is:

ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined

I'm not to sure what this means or why it isn't defined. Do I have to import something to use this? How do I even import namespaces or assemblies in javascript at all?

Thanks

Comment: are you doing this in the browser or node?

Comment: Not sure to be honest, gonna say browser. I am coding this using cloud 9 ide which I'm not sure if it has node or not